# BindingContext is not working in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I use the below code to bind data to a label for changing a slider value and it works fine.

```
 <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" >
    <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference slider1}, Path=Value, StringFormat='Value is {0:F2}'}"
           Opacity="{Binding Source={x:Reference slider1}, Path=Value}"
           x:Name="label1"/>
    <Slider x:Name="slider1"></Slider>
 </StackLayout>
```

In **xaml.cs** page, I have initiated the slider value to 0.5

```
   public MainPage()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       slider1.Value=0.5;
   }
```

[image]

But, when I want to Binding data using **BindingContext**, it does not show the output correctly.

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" >
    <Label BindingContext="x:Reference slider1" 
           Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='Value is {0:F2}'}"
           Opacity="{Binding Value}"
           x:Name="label1"/>
    <Slider x:Name="slider1"></Slider>
 </StackLayout>
```

[image]

What is the problem with my second xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you have missed the {}. Try

```
<Label BindingContext="{x:Reference slider1}"
```

instead of

```
<Label BindingContext="x:Reference slider1"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `BindingContext` then the object should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Slider doesn't implement this interface. Generally, you should assign `BindableProperty` to `BindingContext`.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties/